# Trying to find row numbers that match a criterion starting next search at one row below previous result

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a pile of data on expenditures by the U.S. House of Representatives.  I'd like to find TRAVEL expenses, then calculate the remainder as TOTAL - TRAVEL.  The problem is the rows are not evenly spaced. The most common is six rows between successive TRAVEL rows.  But it can be more or less.

I've used this function to find the first instance of TRAVEL (on the worksheet '2021Q4 working (2)'): `=MIN(IF('2021Q4 working (2)'!E29:$E$5460="TRAVEL",ROW(E29:$E$5460)))`

For the next instance I'd like to start the search at the row after the row returned by the above function.  In this case, the function returns 31.  Thus the code is `=MIN(IF('2021Q4 working (2)'!E32:$E$5460="TRAVEL",ROW(E32:$E$5460)))`

I've tried all manner of variants using `'=MIN(IF(INDIRECT("'2021Q4 working (2)'!E"&lU3+1&":$E$5460=TRAVEL,ROW(E"&U3+1&":$E$5460))))`

The sheet '2021Q4 working (2)' is filtered on STATE.  Examples shown are for CA.

I suspect there are easier and/or more elegant ways to handle this.  Thanks for any help.  Screen caps attached.

**Sheet '2021Q4 working**
[image: Sheet '2021Q4 working (2)']

**Sheet 'CA'**
[image: Sheet 'CA']

Comment: I would be using `FILTER`

Comment: Since we are talking not so much about selecting rows based on the “Name-Expense Item Travel” attribute, but about summing based on these two characteristics, I would recommend looking at the [**SUMIFS() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b). In addition, [**PivotTable**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) will also cope well with this task.